# passing array value to element inside ng-repeat

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

ok, i have something like this:

```
<td>{{row.sku}}</td>
<td>{{row.name}}</td>
<td>{{row.type}}</td>
<td>{{row.category.label}}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{row.price | currency : "€"}}</td>
<td>{{row.description}}</td>
<td>{{row.state}}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{row.amount}}</td>
```

and i want to change this thing in something like this

```
<td ng-repeat="row in displayed">{{row.[value]}}</td>
```

can you suggest me if there is a way?

Comment: More information would be very helpful. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish currently.

Comment: i want to know if is possible to iterate all the element in first code block with the ng-repeat directive and pass trough the [] brackets an array with all the values,

the final result must be the same as the first block

Comment: array=[sku,name,type etc..];
<td ng-repeat="row in displayed">{{row.[array element]}}</td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in vm.array">
    <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in row ">{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

here a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jIK7bnRxvZl1vjqANwcj?p=preview)

Comment: this is exactly what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

See the following simple example.
[demo plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/98CRwsYAvw3rDLwHb8IN?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
  $scope.displayed = [
    {"one":"one", "two":"two", "three":"three"},
    {"one":"1", "two":"2", "three":"3"}];
})
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Test table</h1>
    <table ng-controller="MyController">
      <tr ng-repeat="row in displayed">
        <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in row">{{row[key]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```